# How to compile V-USB for arduino?

Tags: c++, assembly, arduino, avr-gcc

Simply put, I downloaded a port of [V-USB for Arduino](http://vusb-for-arduino.googlecode.com) and can't seem to compile the example that came with it. I get the following message when trying to compile using Arduino IDE 1.0.1

```
avr-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-assembler-with-cpp'
```

I understand that this is most likely version incompatibility issue and could be avoided by downgrading my avr-gcc to an older version, but is it possible to do some trick to make it compile using the up to date version of avr-gcc?

Just a few notes about environment I'm trying this on

- **OS**: Fedora release 17 (Beefy Miracle)
- **avr-gcc**: (Fedora 4.7.2-1.fc17) 4.7.2
- **Arduino IDE**: (arduino-1.0.1-1.fc17) 1.0.1

Comment: BTW, for Windows users - don't bother testing just to prove it works, since I know it works perfectly fine on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the hints from [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester) I managed to solve this problem by updating the IDE to version *1.0.3* (1.0.2 might work as well) and it worked like a charm.

So I guess the problem wasn't the code or compiler, the problem was that the IDE *1.0.1* was expecting an older version of the **avr-gcc** and used a deprecated flag for compiling and simply failed since that flag is no longer available on the new compiler so you either have to downgrade the compiler or upgrade the IDE and from my perspective, upgrading is always the right choice to make.

Answer (score 1):

The `-assembler-with-cpp` option instructs the compiler to consider all following files to be assembler files requiring preprocessing. From a quick glance in v-usb, they provide `.asm` wrappers for `.S` files. You don't need to use those and the compiler will recognize the `.S` files automatically without any options.

If the problem isn't with the `.asm` wrappers detailed above, you can rename the files in question to `.S`.

Have you tried compiling without the flag? What happened?

Comment: No, I haven't tried compiling without flags, the problem is that I'm not passing in any flags in the first place and IDE seems to add it on it's own with. Fortunately, that led me to conclusion that there's something terribly wrong with my IDE thinking that such flag even exists on the avr-gcc compiler so I decided to actually install the IDE manually and to my surprise and at the same time luck Arduino IDE 1.0.3 compiled the sketch without any issues, so thanks for the hints even if they weren't the answer I was looking for